# Find a value of $t$ that satisfies $S = \log2t + \log4t$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

How would I find a value of $t$ that satisfies $S = \log2t + \log4t$?

Comment: Hint:  $\log A +\log B = \log AB$.

Comment: I think you should clarify in which of the followng situations you are: 1) some-one has given you a number $S$ and now you are tasked with finding a $t$ satisfying the equation or 2) You are looking for just any example of a pair (S, t) that satisfies the equation.

Comment: Also, I guess that the reason for the downvotes (not by me) is that you have not described what you already tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

From the logarithmic properties we have $S=\log(2t \times 4t)=\log(8t^2)$

Therefore, $8t^2=e^S \implies t= \sqrt{\frac{e^S}{8}}$ (supposing the logarith is with base $e$. If the logarithm is with base $10$ then $t=  \sqrt{\frac{10^S}{8}}$).

If we knew the value of $S$ we could substitute and find the numerical value of $t$.

Comment: Use `\log` $\log$ instead of `log` $log$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor You're right

Answer (score 2):

$$S=\log(8t^2)$$ or
$$t^2=\frac{10^S}{8}$$ or since $t>0$,
$$t=\frac{10^{\frac{S}{2}}}{2\sqrt2}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT only using the fact that $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$
$$
\log(2t) + \log(4t) = \log(2) + \log(t) + \log(4) + \log(t) = \log(2\cdot 4) + 2\log(t)
$$
Then you can extract $t$.